# how to store the response of a service in a model with alamofire

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, swifty-json

I am learning to programme in swift, I developed with android previously the consumption of services and stored them in a model with the help of retrofit and serializable. Now in swift, I use the Alamofire 4.0 and SwiftyJson to consume a service and the problem is how to save all the response JSON in a model and then use this data, I have reviewed several examples but I still do not understand how to do it.
Could you tell me how to do it or what I need to add to complete this action to get the information and then use it
so I consume the service

```
static func loginService(email : String, password : String, completionHandler : @escaping (LoginResponse) -> Void){
        let parameters : Parameters  = ["email": email, "password": password]
        Alamofire.request(AlamofireConstants.LOGIN, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseData { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("error ==> \(error)")
            case .success(let data):
                do{
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
                    print(result)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is my model

```
    struct LoginResponse : Decodable {
    let user : User?
    let status: Int
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
}

struct User : Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let firstName, lastName, surName, email: String
    let emailToken: String?
    let validate: String
    let token, nationality, documentType, documentNumber: String?
    let legalName, legalNumber, birthdate: String?
    let gender: String
    let phoneMovil, phoneFix, icon: String?
    let wishOffers, acceptTerms, isCustomer: Int
    let active: Bool
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String
}
```

and this is the json from response

```
  {
"user": {
    "id": 183,
    "first_name": "teste",
    "last_name": "testet",
    "sur_name": "este",
    "email": "adeveloper964@gmail.com",
    "email_token": null,
    "validate": "S",
    "token": null,
    "nationality": null,
    "document_type": null,
    "document_number": null,
    "legal_name": null,
    "legal_number": null,
    "birthdate": null,
    "gender": "O",
    "phone_movil": null,
    "phone_fix": null,
    "icon": null,
    "wish_offers": 0,
    "accept_terms": 1,
    "is_customer": 0,
    "active": true,
    "created_at": "2019-05-13 17:04:50",
    "updated_at": "2019-05-14 10:19:31"
},
"status": 0,
"success": true,
"message": ""
```

}

I get this error

> keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "firstName", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"firstName\", intValue: nil) (\"firstName\").", underlyingError: nil))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why SwiftyJSON? You don't need that. To parse JSON into a model `Decodable` is much easier to use and it's built-in (no dependencies).

```
struct LoginResponse : Decodable {

    let user: User
    let status: Int
    let success : Bool
    let message : String
}

struct User : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let firstName, lastName, surName, email : String
}


static func loginService(user : String, password : String){
    Alamofire.request(AlamofireConstants.BASE_URL_TEST + "/api/loginuser", method: .post, parameters: ["email":user,"password":password], encoding: URLEncoding.default)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseData { response in // note the change to responseData
            switch response.result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            case .success(let data):
                do {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                    let result = try decoder.decode(LoginResponse.self, from: data)
                    print(result)
                } catch { print(error) }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the JSON in the question it is.

Comment: Of course there is this json I just want to know if the model I made is correct or there is another way to do it

Comment: If you don't get an error the model is correct. It depends on the **real** JSON you receive.

Comment: if it works, but now I only have this doubt because I am testing it and it gives me the following error, I have updated my json and I would like to know then according to your example how my model should be.

Comment: I updated the answer. To convert the *snake_cased* keys to *camelCased* struct members you have to add the `.convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy to the decoder.

Comment: this message of error : keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "firstName", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "user", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"firstName\", intValue: nil) (\"firstName\").", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: Once again, my answer **is** an example. Note the key decoding strategy

Comment: Run the code, if there is no error the model is correct, otherwise fix the error. The Codable errors are very descriptive. The model looks correct.

Comment: if I apologize I was writing the code badly, really excellent if it works but what happens with the rest of the JSON fields? because he also planned to use them

Comment: Your edited model in the question is OK. Please learn to read JSON. It's pretty easy.

Comment: Of course I understand how to read JSON, only that I did not see your answer updated, man really thanks for the discomfort, it is fantastic the camel_case and snack_case !! I will mark your answer as the solution! thanks again !!

Answer (score 1):

`import SwiftyJSON` in the class where you wrote loginService API and under success case write:

```
case .success(let value):
  let json = JSON(value)
  let loginModel = LoginResponse(json: json)
  print("Login Model is: \(loginModel)")
```

and see if it works